# Sqoop teradata table whith same columns title

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop

I've got an error importing data from teradate to an Hadoop cluster using Sqoop.

My tera table have 2 columns title (not columns name)equivalent. Is there an automatic way to use col name instead of col title in my sqoop job ?

I've tried to use a "Select * from table" as a query but does not work.

And I can't change col title in teradata.

Here my job code :

`sqoop job -Dmapred.job.queue.name=shortduration \
             --create inc_My_Table \
             -- import \
             --connect jdbc:teradata://RCT/DATABASE=DWHBIG \
             --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver \
             --username MBIGDATA -P \
             --query "select a.* from My_Table a where \$CONDITIONS" \
             --target-dir /data/source/fb/$i \
             --check-column DAT_MAJ_DWH \
             --incremental  append \
             --last-value 2001-01-01 \
             --split-by ID`

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_selecting_the_data_to_import) you can use `--columns` to specify column names (along with `--tables` and `--where`).  But I think your query should work.  What error are you getting?

Comment: I've alredy tried ... but I still have the eror duplicate columns name. In teradata I've got two cols who have the same title ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Teradata JDBC Driver 16.00.00.28, you can use connection URL parameter [COLUMN_NAME](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#URL_COLUMN_NAME) to control the behavior of the getColumnName and getColumnLabel to return the column name, column title, or As-clause name, That should resolve your problem.

- COLUMN_NAME=OFF (the default) specifies that the
  ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName method should return the AS-clause
  name if available, or the column name if available, or the column
  title, and specifies that the ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel method
  should return the column title.
- COLUMN_NAME=ON specifies that, when StatementInfo parcel support is
  available, the ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName method should return
  the column name if available, and specifies that the
  ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel method should return the AS-clause
  name if available, or the column name if available, or the column
  title. This option has no effect when StatementInfo parcel support is
  unavailable.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution. I aliased the column that was causing the issue using the `AS` SQL command!